# appcfg.py: command not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've created sample app based on the tutorial link [Hello, World! in 5 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/)

When uploading to Google cloud with command `appcfg.py -A my-test-app -V v1  update helloworld/` then I'm getting `appcfg.py: command not found` on terminal.

Please help.

Comment: Is python on you PATH? Has appcfg.py set flags to be executable?

Comment: Yes.. but I could mange it by "gcloud preview app deploy"

Comment: Try: ./appcfg.py -A my-test-app -V v1  update helloworld/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [add](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) the google_appengine directory to your PATH:

> export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/google_appengine/